# JsonFormat.printer().print() doesn't accept my Message

Tags: android, protocol-buffers

I'm developing an app using AndroidStudio, and I'm using protobuf to transmit data over Bluetooth Low Energy.
But I also need to be able to represent this data in Json, due to environment constraints.
I found JsonFormat to do the job, but unfortunately I'm having trouble with it.
If I want to apply JsonFormat.printer().print() to one of my Message, the project doesn't compile and the method is underlined in red: `print(com.google.protobuf.MessageOrBuilder) in Printer cannot be applied to MyMessage`.
I have the same problem if I pass a builder instead of a message.
Everything else is working smoothly.
My build.gradle contains

```
classpath "com.google.protobuf:protobuf-gradle-plugin:0.8.7"
classpath 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.4.0'
classpath 'com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.0.0'
classpath 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java-util:3.4.0'
```

and

```
implementation 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.4.0'
implementation 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java-util:3.4.0'
```

Does anyone has any idea of what can be the issue?
Thanks

Comment: Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49433473/how-does-jsonformat-printer-print-work Hope it helps

Comment: The issue was caused by protobuf-lite, I had to recompile a java-only version, that is know working smoothly (albeit less adequate for mobile environment). Thanks!